# g++ prints .o file to console

Tags: c++, mingw

When I try to build .o files from source files with g++, compiler outputs .o file to cmd output. And it is no matter what sources I use and how much ("g++ -c foo.cpp -o foo.o" and "g++ -c foo.cpp bar.cpp". "g++ foo.cpp" command works fine.
Compiler mingw 7.3.0 x64

Comment: can u plz add the entire terminal input/output as well?

Comment: That's an extraordinary claim, and I doubt that anyone will believe you unless you present some actual evidence.

Comment: Oh... It takes whole day for me to find an answer for this issue. And the answer is... my stupidity. I have a project of three source files:a.cpp b.cpp and c.cpp (names are for example). I use make to compile my project, and there are constructions like "&(SRC:.cpp=.o)". I don't know how, but one of my .cpp files was built into object file and rewritten. So I have an object file, named with.cpp extension. And I've tried to build.o from it. Sorry for your time

Comment: @Tokorokot Good that you found the issue. What puzzles me is that you are still using MinGW 7.3.0, that version is a bit outdated (current is 10.2.0).